# C# (windows app 8.1) HMAC SHA256 differs from other languages (too short?)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a method that generates a checksum using HMAC SHA256 in both Ruby and Objective-C and I'm trying to port it to C#. It seems like the C# implementation is creating a hashed string that is too short: The Ruby version:

```
message = "POSThttp://api.somewhere.com/eventsmy_data1423778684"
key = "ABC123"
checksum = Digest::HMAC.hexdigest(message, key, Digest::SHA256)
```

gives '83f47bcd10c7360614bb8a858786eb588be3494f1e9bf8a1769bd5f6fff0a3b8'

While the C# version

```
public string GetSHA256Key(string hashKey, string stringToSign)
        {
            MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA256");
            BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
            var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(stringToSign, encoding);
            IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(hashKey, encoding);
            CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
            IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);
            return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage);
        }
```

Returns 'g/R7zRDHNgYUu4qFh4brWIvjSU8em/ihdpvV9v/wo7g=' for the same key/message.

This website also returns the same hashed string as the non C# implementation http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# code works as you intend, except that you return the base64 encoded version of the HMAC.

Change the return line to

```
return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(signedMessage);
```

and it should return what you expect.